# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in plotly

Tags: python, charts, plotly, typeerror

```
from time import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
def PrintChartData():
  data = pd.read_csv("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
  return data

def PrintDataChart():
    data = pd.read_csv("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
    chart_data= go.candlestick(x=data['time'],open=data['open'],high=data['high'],low=data['low'],close=data['close'])
  fig = go.figure(data=[chart_data])
  print(fig.show())
```

RESULT :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-892406758100> in <module>
----> 1 PrintDataChart()

<ipython-input-12-2e832d51e638> in PrintDataChart()
      1 def PrintDataChart():
      2   data = pd.read_csv("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
----> 3   chart_data = go.candlestick(x=data['time'],open=data['open'],high=data['high'],low=data['low'],close=data['close'])
      4   fig = go.figure(data=[chart_data])
      5   print(fig.show())

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
I want to call a .csv file to a dart
But I encountered this error message.

Comment: There's a typo - `go.candlestick` should be [`go.Candlestick`](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- dynamically creating hard coded file referenced in you code to make it runnable on any environment
- two typos in your code

  1. `candlestick()` should be `Candlestick()`
  2. `figure()` should be `Figure()`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
from pathlib import Path


# setup some data so code works
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/currency/eurusd/downloaddatapartial?startdate=08/03/2022%2000:00:00&enddate=09/02/2022%2023:59:59&daterange=d30&frequency=p1d&csvdownload=true&downloadpartial=false&newdates=false"
        ).text
    )
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.rename(columns={c: c.lower() for c in d.columns}).rename(
        columns={"date": "time"}
    )
).to_csv(
    f
)


from time import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

def PrintChartData():
    data = pd.read_csv("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
    return data


def PrintDataChart():
    data = pd.read_csv("eurusd_m1_03.03.2022.csv")
    chart_data = go.Candlestick(
        x=data["time"],
        open=data["open"],
        high=data["high"],
        low=data["low"],
        close=data["close"],
    )
    fig = go.Figure(data=[chart_data])
    print(fig.show())


PrintDataChart()
```

Comment: So, if I want the user to upload a new file every time or several files at the beginning of the work, how should I write a code for input ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code. It got much better and I understood where the mistake was.

Comment: 1. have a specified directory that user uploads files to and mandate a predefined format for the filename. 2. you see I have used **Path** for filename handling, much better practice.  with that you can use `glob()` to locate files that user has uploaded

Comment: Do you think flask can be used for this?

Comment: yes of course - you can upload data through a flask app and then generate a plotly graph